# (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-common: make failed with error code 2

Tags: hadoop, cmake, openssl, maven-3, protocol-buffers

i am trying to compile Hadoop from source and i get this error and i don't know what is the problem or how to solve it 
. i installed all the Requirements that are needed as the instructions says :

1. openJDK
2. maven
3. libssl-dev
4. build-essential
5. pkgconf
6. cmake
7. protobuf-2.5.0

i used the command "mvn package -Pdist,native -DskipTests -Dtar" and i am using Ubuntu version 18.0.4LTS and Hadoop 2.9.1

```html
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Main ................................. SUCCESS [  1.369 s]

[INFO] Apache Hadoop Build Tools .......................... SUCCESS [  0.738 s]

[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  1.038 s]

[INFO] Apache Hadoop Annotations .......................... SUCCESS [  1.796 s]

[INFO] Apache Hadoop Assemblies ........................... SUCCESS [  0.186 s]

[INFO] Apache Hadoop Project Dist POM ..................... SUCCESS [  1.516 s]

[INFO] Apache Hadoop Maven Plugins ........................ SUCCESS [  3.582 s]

[INFO] Apache Hadoop MiniKDC .............................. SUCCESS [  4.147 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth ................................. SUCCESS [  4.336 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Auth Examples ........................ SUCCESS [  2.946 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common ............................... FAILURE [  7.948 s]
[INFO] Apache Hadoop NFS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop KMS .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Common Project ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Client .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Native Client ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HttpFS ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS BookKeeper Journal .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS-NFS ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop HDFS Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN API ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Common .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server Common ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Registry ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN NodeManager ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Web Proxy ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ApplicationHistoryService ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Service ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN ResourceManager ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Server Tests .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Client .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN SharedCacheManager .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Plugin Storage ......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Router .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN TimelineService HBase Backend ... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Timeline Service HBase tests .... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Applications .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN DistributedShell ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Unmanaged Am Launcher ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Site ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN UI .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop YARN Project ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Client ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Core ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Common ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Shuffle .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce App ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce HistoryServer .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce JobClient .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce HistoryServer Plugins ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Examples ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop MapReduce Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distributed Copy ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archives ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Archive Logs ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Rumen ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Gridmix .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Data Join ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Ant Tasks ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Extras ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Pipes ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop OpenStack support .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Amazon Web Services support .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Azure support ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Mini-Cluster ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Scheduler Load Simulator ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Resource Estimator Service ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Azure Data Lake support .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools Dist ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Distribution ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Cloud Storage ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Hadoop Cloud Storage Project ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.766 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-07-08T16:31:14+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 82M/764M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:2.9.0:cmake-compile (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-common: make failed with error code 2 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-maven-plugins:2.9.0:cmake-compile (cmake-compile) on project hadoop-common: make failed with error code 2
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: make failed with error code 2
    at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.cmakebuilder.CompileMojo.runMake (CompileMojo.java:231)
    at org.apache.hadoop.maven.plugin.cmakebuilder.CompileMojo.execute (CompileMojo.java:98)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:955)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-common
```

Comment: Show the errors from when you `Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.`

Comment: I did it and passed the result in this [file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12mS_B_ex4IQVYrqY_4ASYFDdnk54_kow)

Comment: The errors are related to openssl, try installing that

Answer (score 0):

as per Hadoop official [github](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/BUILDING.txt) CMake 3.1 is required and can be found here at [cmake.org](https://cmake.org/files/v3.1/). Building non-native is also an alternative: 
`build:mvn clean package -DskipTests -Dtar`

That ended up breaking elsewhere for me on Hadoop 3.2.1.

What worked is to really giving up on building from source and downloading the precompiled binaries at:

https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html